# Including php menu, assigning active class to the links on click

Tags: javascript, php, css

PHP, CSS, and JS speakers! )
I am including a menu in a php file. I need it, because it takes less time to change the links. However, the task is now with **ACTIVE links**. When I click a link, *it should take the active as well as the parent links also should take an active link*.
I did it with PHP, which works fine , but if I continue, there will be a lot of php statements and **it may also affect the performance**, and it has a bad  affect on *readability* of the code. Please have a look at the below code (this is just a FRAGMENT) of the code, i.e. 1 section of the menu, not the whole menu )

```
  <!--  TAJIKISTAN section start -->
          <li class="megamenu"><a   <?php if($activePageL0 == "tajikistan") { echo "class = \"mn-has-sub active button_open \" "; }else {echo "class = \"mn-has-sub button_open \" ";} ?> >Tajikistan <i class="fa fa-angle-down button_open"></i></a>
            <!-- Sub-->
            <ul class="mn-sub mn-has-multi">
             <li <?php if($activePageL1 == "tajikistan-sub") { echo "class = \"mn-sub-multi active button_open\" "; }else {echo "class = \" mn-sub-multi button_open \" ";} ?> > <a class="mn-group-title button_open">Tajikistan</a>
                <ul>
                  <li <?php if($activePageL2 == "tajikistan-history") { echo "class = \"active\" "; }else {echo "class = \" \" ";} ?> ><a href="<?php echo "$root/$lang"; ?>/tajikistan-history.php">History</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Culture </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Holidays</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Short info</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="mn-sub-multi"><a class="mn-group-title">Mountains</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">The Pamirs</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fann </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Peak Ismoili Somoni</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">K.Marx & F.Engles</a></li>

                </ul>
              </li>

            </ul>
            <!-- End Sub-->
          </li>
           <li class="slash">/</li>
           <!-- End Tajikistan -->
```

Question: Is there any way to handle it with PHP or Java Script or anything?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are your href adresses look like? Do they refer to a url or do they act like ajax requests on click event listeners? Can you give an example url, which stands exemplary for the urls in the menu?

Comment: Use PHP, JS there will be messy. Look, is not so complicated if you know the paths: `class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/home.php" ? "active" : "");?>"`

Comment: You can resume your conditions like this: `class="<?php echo (($activePageL2 == "tajikistan-history") ? "active" : "");?>"`

Comment: @Marcel thanks for your reply. I am not using ajax. The site is offline ((

Comment: @Troyer thank you for your reply. The problem is that if I use like above even, for every link I have to put in the menu file one php statement. The result I get to much php statements and it will be too difficult to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all your menu links to single array:

```
$menu = [
  [
    'title' => 'home',
    'url' => 'index.php',
  ],
  [
    'title' => 'Menu with dropdown',
    'key' => 'subs',
    'items' => [
       [
         'title' => 'Sub 1',
         'url' => 'page/sub1',
       ],
       [
          'title' => 'Sub 2',
          'url' => 'page/sub2',
       ],
       ...
    ],
    ...
  ]
]
```

Now use recursive function to run through `$menu` and generate your menu structure:

```
showMenu($menu);

function showMenu(&$menu, $level = 0) {
    foreach ($menu as $item) {

       $class = getItemClass($item, $level).' '.(isActive($item['key'], $level) ? ' active' : '');

       if (isset($item['items'])) {
           echo "<ul>";
           echo "<li class='{$class}'>";
           showMenu($item, $level + 1);
           echo "</li>";
           echo "</ul>";
       } else {
           echo "<li class='{$class}'><a href='{$item['url']}'>{$item['title']}</a></li>";
       }
    }
}
```

Using recursive function you can have virtually any number of levels.

`getItemClass` should return class string depending on `$level`

`isActive` should return true/false if current URL matches item URL.

---

If you do not reload page, than you can go with jQuery option.

On page load set active element via PHP, than on link click remove all `.active` classes, and add only to parents.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');

    $(this)
      .closest('li')
      .addClass('active')
      .parents('ul')
      .addClass('active')
      .last()
      .removeClass('active');

  })
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sub > li > ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.active {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
li.active,
li.active a {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li class="title">Sub Items</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my example using jquery. In your case, you can just render the active class to last child menu selected then using jquery to apply css rule to parents of this node.

```js
$('li').click(function (){
 $(this).children('span:first-child').addClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li span:first-child').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
li{
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
.active{
  background-color: #12323A;
}

li:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><span>Level 1</span></li>
 <li><span>level 2</span>
   <ul>
     <li><span>Level 2.1</span></li>
     <li> <span>Level 3</span>
       <ul>
       <li><span>Level 3.1</span></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```